# How to implement ^ operator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, operator-overloading, fractions

I'm working on creating a bunch of instances for a Fraction data type in Haskell, and I'm wondering if there's a place I would be able to implement the `^` operator.

What I mean is, I've got several instances of various `Num` types, and within those instances, I define common operations such as `+`, `-`, etc.

With that, the data type behaves as a normal number, as I want it to (meaning I can call things like `(Frac 1 2) + (Frac 1 4)` and get back `Frac 3 4`)

What I'm trying to do is implement `^` directly. Right now, I've got it defined like this:

```
(|^|) :: Fraction -> Int -> Fraction
(|^|) f = foldr (*) mempty . flip replicate f
```

When I try to change the name of the function to `^`, I get an error because it conflicts with Prelude's definition of `^`. Is there a `Num` type I can give my `Fraction` type an instance of to allow me to use the `^` operator on it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `Num` instance for `Fraction`? If so, the Prelude `^` will work for `Fraction`.

Comment: @dbaupp Holy crap! That's awesome! I had no idea, but yes, I did, and yes, it works! Thanks!

Comment: Note @sepp2k's point about the type signature. If a type satisfies all the constraints (the stuff before `=>`) of a function, then it can be used in that function. In this case, the relevant constraint is `Num a`, so *any* type with a `Num` instance can be used with `^`.

Comment: By the way, I would recommended that you do not provide a `Monoid` instance for numeric types; `Data.Monoid` provides the `Sum` and `Product` wrappers for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Prelude.^` is not part of any type class, so the only way you can define your own `^` function would be to hide the one from `Prelude`.

Note that since the signature of `Prelude.^` is `(Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`, you'll be able to use it on values of your `Frac` type just fine as long as it's an instance of `Num`. You just wouldn't be providing your own implementation.

Comment: Note that `Prelude.^` only works on non-negative integer exponents. But if your type is an instance of `Fractional` (I presume it would be), you can also use `Prelude.^^`, which works on all (including negative) integer exponents.

Comment: And if you want the most general exponentiation operator use `(**)`, which permits exponentiation for floating point bases and exponents.

Comment: And of course, this is the reason why we have three exponentiation operators in the first place, as you can see from their types: `(^)` requires `Num`, `(^^)` requires `Fractional` and `(**)` requires `Floating`.